# Get data from multiple tables by two timestamp

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

PostgreSQL 10.12

I have a table with calculated data grouped by date with hour, e.g.:

```
hourly_stats
clicks_count | visitors_count | product_id | promoter_id | bundle_id | date_time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     15      |        6       |     123    |     456     |    789    | 2018-11-02 12:00:00
     8       |        3       |     123    |     456     |    789    | 2018-11-02 16:00:00
     2       |        1       |     123    |     456     |    789    | 2018-11-13 10:00:00
     5       |        2       |     123    |     456     |    789    | 2018-11-13 21:00:00
```

Every new hour I collect statistics for the previous hour and insert it into the table.

In addition, to always display fresh data, I use a materialized view, which stores the calculated data from the beginning of the current hour to the current moment (refreshed every 5 minutes).

The core part of the query is always based on two timestamp values and looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        clicks_count,
        visitors_count,
        product_id,
        promoter_id,
        bundle_id,
        date_time
    FROM hourly_stats
    UNION ALL (
        SELECT
            clicks_count,
            visitors_count,
            product_id,
            promoter_id,
            bundle_id,
            date_time
        FROM materialized_stats
    )
)
WHERE (date_time > start_date AND date_time <= end_date)
```

This core part is used in multiple really complex queries, which are too slow. For example, it takes more than a 1.5 minute to complete the query (if no row is filtered by `start_date` and `end_date`) if table has more than 20 million records in one of the cases.

---

I decided to add two more table with calculated data grouped by year-month-day:

```
daily_stats
clicks_count | visitors_count | product_id | promoter_id | bundle_id | date_time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     23      |        9       |     123    |     456     |    789    | 2018-11-02
     7       |        3       |     123    |     456     |    789    | 2018-11-13
```

and by year-month:

```
monthly_stats
clicks_count | visitors_count | product_id | promoter_id | bundle_id | date_time
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     30      |       12       |     123    |     456     |    789    | 2018-11
```

So, if I have `start_date = '2019-01-01 00:00:00'` and `end_date = '2020-08-12 16:00:00'` I will be able to collect data like this

```
(SELECT
    clicks_count,
    visitors_count,
    product_id,
    promoter_id,
    bundle_id,
    date_time
FROM monthly_stats
WHERE 'monthly_condition')
UNION ALL
(SELECT
    clicks_count,
    visitors_count,
    product_id,
    promoter_id,
    bundle_id,
    date_time
FROM daily_stats
WHERE 'daily_condition')
UNION ALL
(SELECT
    clicks_count,
    visitors_count,
    product_id,
    promoter_id,
    bundle_id,
    date_time
FROM hourly_stats
WHERE 'hourly_condition')
UNION ALL (
SELECT
    clicks_count,
    visitors_count,
    product_id,
    promoter_id,
    bundle_id,
    date_time
FROM materialized_stats
)
```

---

Each calculated row is added to the corresponding table only after the base time period (month, day, or hour) is over. So for specific set of `product_id | promoter_id | bundle_id` I should get:

- 19 rows from `monthly_stats` +
- 11 rows from `daily_stats` +
- 16 rows from `hourly_stats` +
- 1 row from `materialized_stats`

Already implemented restrictions (on a application layer):

1. max `end_date` value may be equal to the end of the current day
2. `start_date` is always less than `end_date`
3. `start_date` and `end_date` values ​​are specified with an hour precision

Question: how to implement these 'monthly_condition', 'daily_condition' and 'hourly_condition' above? They should be based on the `start_date` and `end_date` parts, but I quite don't understand how to do this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem.  I had to solve this once before for SQL Server.  PostgreSQL makes it much easier.  Everything down to the `fullness` cte has been tested.  The `allstats` cte is a best guess since I do not have your tables or data.

```
with invars as (
  select '2016-08-15 12:35:00'::timestamptz as start_date,
         '2020-08-12 19:00:00'::timestamptz as end_date
), days as (
  select c.dhour, 
         tstzrange(
           date_trunc('hour', i.start_date), 
           date_trunc('hour', i.end_date), '[)') as qrange
    from invars i
   cross join lateral generate_series(
                date_trunc('hour', i.start_date),
                date_trunc('hour', i.end_date),
                interval '1 hour'
              ) as c(dhour)
), calendar as (
  select dhour,
         date_trunc('day', dhour) as dday,
         date_trunc('month', dhour) as dmonth,
         qrange
    from days
), fullness as (
  select dhour, dday, dmonth, qrange,
         qrange @> tstzrange(dday, dday + interval '1 day', '[)') as full_day,
         qrange @> tstzrange(dmonth, dmonth + interval '1 month', '[)') as full_month
    from calendar
), allstats as (
  select clicks_count, visitors_count, product_id, promoter_id, bundle_id
    from monthly_stats
   where date_time in (select distinct to_char(dmonth, 'YYYY-MM') 
                         from fullness where full_month)
  union all
  select clicks_count, visitors_count, product_id, promoter_id, bundle_id
    from daily_stats
   where date_time in (select distinct to_char(dday, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
                         from fullness where full_day and not full_month)
  union all
  select clicks_count, visitors_count, product_id, promoter_id, bundle_id
    from hourly_stats
   where date_time in (select dhour from fullness 
                        where not full_day and not full_month 
                          and dhour < date_trunc(hour, now()))
  union all
  select clicks_count, visitors_count, product_id, promoter_id, bundle_id
    from materialized_stats
)
select * from allstats;
```

I think your problem description leaves off the fact that the `start_date` can begin in the middle of a month or even a day.  This query covers that.

Comment: Thank! I hope that this approach of splitting tables will really help improve performance.

Comment: @taras It should help a lot.  With this approach your absolute worst case for hourly/daily records is 106 (e.g. `2020-07-01 01:00:00` to `2020-08-31 23:59:00`).  If pulling from your hourly table only, 106 records do not cover even five days.  Good luck!